# show/hide two divs based on browser with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 wufoo forms in their own divs and I need to show/hide each one based on the browser. I need to show one in chrome and show the other one in firefox. I'd preferably like to do this in javascript. Any ideas?

Comment: [check it out](https://modernizr.com/)

Comment: Modernizr, as @freestock.tk said, is pretty good. If you want a more lightweight solution, you want to sniff the useragent string for browser-specific stuff between Chrome and Firefox, and toggle those divs based on that.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you could filter Firefox, but i have no idea about chrome only.

```css
.ffbrowser {
  display: none;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .anybrowser {
    display: none;
  }
  .ffbrowser {
    display: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="anybrowser">
  <label>any browser but Firefox</label>
</form>
<form class="ffbrowser">
  <label>Firefox</label>
</form>
```

.